# cant get the group of an int field from a query in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a table with a field called 'year'. It has many repetitions in the column so I want to find the distinct group. I have 4 different 'years' in about 20 rows and I dont get these values from the query. Instead what is returned are 4 numbers which are not the years (5,14,4,70). The same code worked fine when I used this with suburb field in another table where there were multiple values of this field. I dont get why this isnt working.

```
//in view
  echo $this->Form->input('year', ['label' => 'Year','options' => $allyears]);

//controller
     $allyears = $this->TimesheetDates->find('list')
                   ->select(['TimesheetDates.id', 'TimesheetDates.year'])
                    ->group(['TimesheetDates.year'])->autoFields(true)
                    ->order(['TimesheetDates.year'=> 'ASC'])
                    ->hydrate(false);

$this->set('allyears',$allyears);


//another controller and this code worked fine
  $suburb = $this->Students->find('list')->where(['Students.address_suburb !=' => '','Students.student_inactive' => 0])
            ->select(['Students.id','Students.address_suburb'])
            ->group(['Students.address_suburb'])->autoFields(true)
            ->order(['Students.address_suburb' => 'ASC'])
            ->hydrate(false);
```

Comment: Is this `(5,14,4,70)` Ids?

Comment: no this isnt the ids or number of years in a group

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the [**documentation**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs) about how `find('list')` works

```
 $allyears = $this->TimesheetDates->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id',
        'valueField' => 'year']
     )
     ->group(['year'])
     ->order(['year'=> 'ASC']);
```

Note that it has no meaning selecting the `id` of the `TimesheetDates` Table as you are grouping by `year` and the `id` is choosen randomly between all the records that share the same year